# Ignore http.post future exception

Tags: flutter, dart, future

How can I ignore a future exception of a `http.post` call? In the following code I want to send a message to the server, but I don't care about the response:

```
  http.post(Uri(host: '10.0.2.2', port: 8000, path: 'log-message', scheme: 'http'),
      body: json.encode({
        'message': 'Event occurred',
      }));
```

If the server at that URL is not running, this exception is thrown:

`SocketException (SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 10.0.2.2, port = 41874)`

I can prevent this exception from being thrown by doing `await` on the above call and wrapping that around a `try-catch`, but I don't want to block. The following code still results in the above exception:

```
  http.post(Uri(host: '10.0.2.2', port: 8000, path: 'log-message', scheme: 'http'),
      body: json.encode({
        'message': 'Event occurred',
      }))
    .catchError((_) => http.Response('Logging message failed', 404));
```

`ignore()` and `onError()` have the same result.

I want ignore whatever exception `http.post` could throw without having to do an `await`, which blocks the code.

Comment: You say: _having to do an await, which blocks the code_ but it doesn't necessarily block. You can adapt Peter's method to remove the response (return Future<void> instead) but await the `http.post`. Now Peter's `myFunction` becomes a fire-and-forget method. Call it, don't await it, yet it catches and swallows the exception.

Comment: 1. `await` does not block.  It's syntactic sugar that calls `Future.then`, `Future.catchError`, etc. for you.  2. Consequently, there's no reason why `.catchError((_) => http.Response(...))` or `.ignore()` shouldn't work.  I just tried them, and both seem to swallow a `SocketException` fine. 3. Post actual code that reproduces the problem.  The code you've posted has a number of errors (current versions of `http.post` require a `Uri` argument, and your URL is malformed).

Comment: I updated the code. Neither ```catchError``` or ```ignore``` swallow the exception. By blocking I meant that it prevents the code below the await call from executing.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks, that works. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just print the error that you catched, it should't block the app.

```
http.post('http:/10.0.2.2/log-message',
                      body: json.encode({
                        'message': 'Event occurred',
                      }));
                    .catchError((_) => print('Logging message failed'));
```

Comment: I had tried that. You still get an exception. You also get this warning: ```A value of type 'void' can't be returned by the 'onError' handler because it must be assignable to 'FutureOr<Response>'```

Comment: Then could you please use Dio instead of http, as I know, dio doesn't catch error if you don't use try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to catch a `SocketException` without waiting for the result of the `http.post` operation, because it occurs later than the request is sent. Whether you use `async/await` with `try/catch` or `.then` and `.catchError` is your choice, but the preferred way is `async/await`:

```
Future<Response> myFunction async {
  try {
    return http.post(...);
  } on SocketException {
    // handle the exception here as you like
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to catch the exception. I just to ignore whatever exception ```http.post``` could throw without having to do ```await```.

Comment: This still results in the uncaught exception.